# Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner at `react.js.`
I got this error:

> Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined
>   full error output in my browser chrome console:
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined
>           at clickOnBlock (bundle.js:21172)
>           at ActionLink (bundle.js:21232)
>           at bundle.js:7557
>           at measureLifeCyclePerf (bundle.js:7327)
>           at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner
>   (bundle.js:7556)
>           at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (bundle.js:7531)
>           at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js:7439)
>           at Object.mountComponent (bundle.js:13856)
>           at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (bundle.js:7622)
>           at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js:7509)

my codes:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var x;
var y;
var z;
var zz;
var counter=0;
function ActionLink() {

    function  clickOnBlock(d) {
        if (counter<2){
            x = d.getAttribute("data-color");
            y = d.getAttribute("data-u");
            document.getElementById("d" + (y)).style.backgroundColor = x;
            document.getElementById("lastClick").value = x;

            if(counter==0) {
                // Store
                localStorage.setItem("keepLast", x);
                // Retrieve
                z= document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("keepLast");
            }

            if(counter==0) {
                // Store
                localStorage.setItem("id", y);
                // Retrieve
                zz= document.getElementById("resultId").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("id");
            }
            counter++;

            if(counter==2){
                if(x==z && y!=zz){
                    yes();
                }else{
                    no();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function no(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            remove();
        }, 1000);
    }

    function remove(){
        document.getElementById("d" + (y)).style.backgroundColor ="";
        document.getElementById("d" + (zz)).style.backgroundColor ="";
        counter=0

    }

    function yes(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            ok();
        }, 1000);
    }
    function ok() {
        document.getElementById("d" + (y)).style.backgroundColor = "";
        document.getElementById("d" + (zz)).style.backgroundColor = "";
        document.getElementById("d" + (y)).style.backgroundColor = "black";
        document.getElementById("d" + (zz)).style.backgroundColor = "black";
        counter=0
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <div id="bigdiv">
                <a id="d1"  type="button" data-u="1" data-color="green" onClick={clickOnBlock(this)}></a>
                <a id="d2"  type="button" data-u="2" data-color="yellow" onClick={clickOnBlock(this)}></a>
                <a id="d3"  type="button" data-u="3" data-color="deeppink" onClick={clickOnBlock(this)}></a>
                <a id="d4"  type="button" data-u="4" data-color="green" onClick={clickOnBlock(this)}></a>
                <br/>
                <a id="d5"  type="button" data-u="5" data-color="blue" onClick={clickOnBlock(this)}></a>
                <a id="d6"  type="button" data-u="6" data-color="orange" onClick={clickOnBlock(this)}></a>
                <a id="d7"  type="button" data-u="7" data-color="deeppink" onClick={clickOnBlock(this)}></a>
                <a id="d8"  type="button" data-u="8" data-color="red" onClick={clickOnBlock(this)}></a>
                <br/>
                <a id="d9"  type="button" data-u="9" data-color="red" onClick={clickOnBlock(this)}></a>
                <a id="d10" type="button" data-u="10" data-color="yellow" onClick={clickOnBlock(this)}></a>
                <a id="d11" type="button" data-u="11" data-color="orange"onClick={clickOnBlock(this)}></a>
                <a id="d12" type="button" data-u="12" data-color="blue" onClick={clickOnBlock(this)}></a>
            </div>
            <input id="lastClick" type="hidden" value="" />
                <div id="result" className="dd" ></div>
                <div id="resultId" className="dd" ></div>
        </div>

    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ActionLink /> ,  document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass event into your function and get attribute with `e.target`:

```
<a id="d1"  type="button" data-u="1" data-color="green" onClick={(e) => clickOnBlock(e)}></a>
```

Or just pass nothing, JS will do it for you:

```
<a id="d1"  type="button" data-u="1" data-color="green" onClick={clickOnBlock}>

function  clickOnBlock(e) {
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute("data-color"));
}
```

Note:

```
onClick={clickOnBlock(param)}
```

This function will execute with every render, without click. You need to pass a function with `onClick` but you are passing a result of this function execute. To avoid this, use an arrow functions:

```
onClick={() => clickOnBlock(param)}
```

Answer (score 0):

When passing an event handler you don't need to invoke the handler or pass `this` as the target.
Try changing the way you pass the handler from this:

```
`onClick={clickOnBlock(this)}`
```

To this:

```
onClick={clickOnBlock}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function  clickOnBlock() {
    return (d) => { if (counter<2){
        x = d.getAttribute("data-color");
        y = d.getAttribute("data-u");
        document.getElementById("d" + (y)).style.backgroundColor = x;
        document.getElementById("lastClick").value = x;

        if(counter==0) {
            // Store
            localStorage.setItem("keepLast", x);
            // Retrieve
            z= document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("keepLast");
        }

        if(counter==0) {
            // Store
            localStorage.setItem("id", y);
            // Retrieve
            zz= document.getElementById("resultId").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("id");
        }
        counter++;

        if(counter==2){
            if(x==z && y!=zz){
                yes();
            }else{
                no();
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

onClick={() => this.clickOnBlock()}